# Spring data JPA entity change not being persisted

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data

I have a Spring data entity (using JPA w/ Hibernate and MySQL) defined as such:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dataset")
public class Dataset {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "guid", nullable = false)
    private String guid;
    @Column(name = "size", nullable = false)
    private Long size;
    @Column(name = "create_time", nullable = false)
    private Date createTime;
    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "created_by")
    private User createdBy;
    @Column(name = "active", nullable = false)
    private boolean active;
    @Column(name = "orig_source", nullable = false)
    private String origSource;
    @Column(name = "orig_source_type", nullable = false)
    private String origSourceType;
    @Column(name = "orig_source_org", nullable = false)
    private String origSourceOrg;
    @Column(name = "uri", nullable = false)
    private String uri;
    @Column(name = "mimetype", nullable = false)
    private String mimetype;
    @Column(name = "registration_state", nullable = false)
    private int registrationState;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "dataset_id")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<DatasetFile> datasetFiles;
```

I have the following repository for this entity:

```
public interface DatasetRepo extends JpaRepository<Dataset, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(p) > 0 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END FROM Dataset p WHERE p.uri = ?1 and p.registrationState>0")
    public Boolean existsByURI(String location);

    @Query("SELECT a FROM Dataset a LEFT JOIN FETCH a.datasetFiles c where a.registrationState>0")
    public List<Dataset> getAll(Pageable pageable);

    @Query("SELECT a FROM Dataset a LEFT JOIN FETCH a.datasetFiles c WHERE a.registrationState>0")
    public List<Dataset> findAll();

    @Query("SELECT a FROM Dataset a LEFT JOIN FETCH a.datasetFiles c where a.guid= ?1")
    public Dataset findByGuid(String guid);
}
```

Now - In a controller, I am fetching a dataset, updating one of its attributes and I would be expecting that attribute change to be flushed to the DB, but it never is.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/storeDataset", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    WebServiceReturn storeDataset(
            @RequestParam(value = "dsGUID", required = true) String datasetGUID,
            @RequestParam(value = "stType", required = true) String stType) {
        WebServiceReturn wsr = null;
        logger.info("stType: '" + stType + "'");
        if (!stType.equals("MongoDB") && !stType.equals("Hive") && !stType.equals("HDFS")) {
            wsr = getFatalWebServiceReturn("Invalid Storage type '" + stType + "'");
        } else if (stType.equals("MongoDB")) {
            /* Here is where I'm reading entity from Repository */
            Dataset dataset = datasetRepo.findByGuid(datasetGUID);
            if (dataset != null) {
                MongoLoader mongoLoader = new MongoLoader();
                boolean success = mongoLoader.loadMongoDB(dataset);
                logger.info("Success: " + success);
                if (success) {
                    /* Here is where I update entity attribute value, this is never flushed to DB */
                    dataset.setRegistrationState(1);
                }
                wsr = getWebServiceReturn(success ? 0 : -1, "Successfully loaded dataset files into " + stType + " storage", "Failed to load dataset files into " + stType + " storage");
            }

        }
        return wsr;
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: So - I'm fairly certain that the entity that comes back from the Spring data query is not managed (at least not the way I'm thinking it is).  If I run `entityManager.contains(dataset)`, that returns `false`.  I can get the changes to persist by running `datasetRepo.save(dataset)`, which merges the changes, however can someone tell me why the entity that comes back from the query isn't managed and how I can get it to be managed?

Comment: Try annotating your method `storeDataset` as `@Transactional`

Comment: You should turn on hibernate query logs to see what's going on under the covers.

Comment: @PauChorro what method are you referring to?  There is no `storeDataset` method in my code.

Comment: I wanted to say you're request mapping `storeDataset` but it is also a method! :)

Comment: @PauChorro ahhh - yes... sorry, you are right, I was not looking at my MVC code.  Let me try that.

Comment: Yes - annotating the MVC request with `@Transactional` fixed the issue.  My understanding was that entities fetched using Spring data were managed by default if using the JPA provider.  Can you explain why they aren't?

Comment: @alessandroferrucci  I've answered you on below post ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to annotate  the method of request mapping with `@Transactional`.

Why? If you want to modify an object in memory and then it is updated transparently in the database you need do it inside an active transaction.

Don't forget you're using JPA (`spring-data` is using `JPA`) and if you want your Entity will be in a `managed state` you need an active transaction.

See:

- http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/update

> Transparent Update Once an entity object is retrieved from the
>   database (no matter which way) it can simply be modified in memory
>   from inside an active transaction:
>
> ```
> Employee employee = em.find(Employee.class, 1);
>
> em.getTransaction().begin();
> employee.setNickname("Joe the Plumber");
> em.getTransaction().commit();
> ```